# Ignore one folder and its contents in batch operation

Tags: batch-file, forfiles

I've tried to create a batch file that will remove all files and sub-directories from a folder.  The command I found that worked is this

```
FORFILES /p “X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY” /m *.* /c “cmd /c Del /F /Q @path” /d -7 /s & FORFILES /p “X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY” /S /D -7 /C “cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path”
```

Now my users tell me there is a Reference folder under 1 MONDAY that they don't want purged (but all other subdirectories should be emptied and deleted.)  Can anyone advise how I might accomplish that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is extremely inefficient to use **FORFILES** for such a task because **FORFILES** has to start `cmd.exe` for each file found to delete the file older than seven days and for each folder to remove.

A much better solution would be:

```
@echo off
%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY" "X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY\WeeklyDelete" /E /XD "X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY\WeeklyDelete" "X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY\Reference" /MINAGE:7 /MOVE /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS
if exist "X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY\WeeklyDelete\" rd /Q /S "X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY\WeeklyDelete"
```

**ROBOCOPY** searches

- for all files in the directory `X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY`
- and its subdirectories including empty directories because of option `/E` with
- excluding the files in the two directories `X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY\WeeklyDelete` and `X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY\Reference` and all their subdirectories because of option `/XD "X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY\WeeklyDelete" "X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY\Reference"` with
- excluding all files last modified in last seven days because of option `/MINAGE:7`.

The found files and folders matching theses criteria are moved to `X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY\WeeklyDelete` whereby the destination folder is automatically created on not already existing.

The options `/NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS` are for **not** printing the list of moved directories, list of moved files, the header and the summary.

A folder is moved only if being empty after moving all files matched by these criteria. So a folder is not moved on containing a file or subfolder.

The option `/S` instead of `/E` and the option `/MOV` instead of `/MOVE` can be used to move only files and do not move also folders being empty before or after moving the files.

The file and folder movements are done very fast by **ROBOCOPY** because of destination folder is on same drive as source folder which means just the file system of this drive must be updated and no file data must be moved at all.

An **IF** condition is used after **ROBOCOPY** finished with updating the file system to move the files and folders to verify if the destination folder `X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY\WeeklyDelete` exists. In this case command **RD** is used to delete this folder quietly because of option `/Q` and with all files and subdirectories because of option `/S`. This action is again just a file system update not really deleting file data stored on storage media and so is processed very fast.

Open a command prompt window and execute there the following commands to read more about the used commands in the three lines above.

- `echo /?`
- `if /?`
- `rd /?`
- `robocopy /?`

The commands are described also

- by **Microsoft** with the documentations for the [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) and
- by **SS64.com** with [A-Z index of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/) and on many other websites.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response!  I have read the documentation, but it wasn't very clear to me how to use "not equal" as well as other things.  Sorry to cause issues with the double post; I thought this question was different enough from the first to merit it.  Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

```bat
for /f %%a in ("X:\Daily\1 MONDAY\*") do (if %%a neq "<filename you want to save>" (del %%a))
```

**NOT YET TESTED**

This should work though. Put the files you want to save in `<filename you want to save>`

Comment: Thank you for your response. :)  Apologies, but I don't know how to use this.  Does it append or precede the FORFILES command?  Does it stand on its own?  I've tried it every which way but it keeps throwing errors.

Comment: Check `for /?`. For is a basic command in many languages but the batch iteration is a little unique. It stands on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your provided information, I would suggest this as your updated batch file:

```batch-file
@%__AppDir__%forfiles.exe /P "X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY" /C "cmd /C If @IsDir == FALSE 0x28Del /A /F @Path0x29 Else If /I Not @File == 0x22Reference0x22 RD /S /Q @Path" /D -7
```

*That's it, nothing else to be added or modified.*

Comment: @unityco, whilst the [tag:forfiles] command is not the most efficient to run, this version is considerably more efficient than what you have posted To begin with it only runs `ForFiles` once, as opposed to twice, and additionally neither of them are recursive. It simply deletes any files and directories older than 7 days in `X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY`, but ignores the `X:\DAILY\1 MONDAY\REFERENCE` directory. Based upon your repeat question, which you should now delete. You can run the same line directly from `cmd.exe` too, (although for that you can remove the first character, `@`, if you wish).